# What is a realizable matroid?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry, matroids

In [note](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ayong/Math595TheGrassmannian/Grlecture2matroids.2011.03.24.pdf) I'm reading, there is a term called realizable matroid.

> Prove that $\mathbb{k}$ is algebraically closed then $M$ is realizable over $\mathbb{k}$ if and only if the following identity of ideals holds:...

I have searched on the Internet, but I haven't found any definition or theorem about the realizability of a matroid.

So what is a realizable matroid?

Please explain for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean representability of matroids: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_representation ?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the linked notes(*) carefully, it would appear that the author uses the standard term "representable" and the nonstandard term "realizable" interchangeably.

(*) It's not an article, it's a set of class notes.  These are certainly not to the same editorial standards as an article or a presentation at a conference.